# makefile conditional - strip whitespace from variable

Tags: if-statement, makefile, conditional-statements, strip

Following the syntax given in the documentation [here](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_7.html).

```
# Makefile
S='    '

spam:
ifneq ($(strip $(S)),)
    @echo nonempty
else
    @echo empty
endif
```

But when executing `make spam`, it still goes into the `nonempty` block here, expected the `empty` block.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make variable assignments aren't like shell assignments. You don't need the quotes.

You are setting the value of your variable to `'    '` and not      like you are expecting.

So strip then converts it to `' '` which is not equal to the empty string.

Remove the quotes on the assignment line.